# Ember-Data: My custom `serializeIntoHash` is returning an empty hash?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

By default when the RESTAdapter sends a request to the server to POST data, it sends the model's `typeKey` as the root of the hash:

```
typeKey: { data }
```

but my server wants a 'rootless' hash:

```
{ data }
```

I discovered that this is the method to overwrite, but something I am doing is causing not only the root to be removed, but the hash itself is also empty... even though my console.log is showing that `record` is being serialized into the hash.

```
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({

    serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {

        console.log(' hash going in: ' + JSON.stringify(hash));  // hash is {} going in

        hash = this.serialize(record, options);

        console.log('hash going out: ' + JSON.stringify(hash)); // hash is { full of data } going out

        return hash;  // after this, for some reason the request goes out as an empty hash {}
    }

});
```

Am i not returning the modified hash correctly?  I also tried these variations:

```
return (hash, type, record, options)
```

and

```
return this._super(hash);
```

and

```
return this._super(hash, type, record, options);
```

Nothing I return seems to work.  I do not know what i am doing wrong?

I noticed in the [API Docs for the method](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.10/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L707), there is no `return` used, but if I exclude that I get the exact same issue, so I dont know if I even need the return or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `serializeIntoHash` method is funky, the caller doesn't expect you to return a hash(as noted), it expects you to modify the hash that was sent in.

That means, if you just set hash, you will no longer be working with the hash that will get sent off.  You will need to set properties/remove properties from that instance.

Here they merge the results so as to accomplish what I'm saying: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.10/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L500

Comment: ok, that makes some sense.  So, if I understand you, i need to get the results of `serialize(record, options)` separately, and somehow loop through and add the properties from the result into keys in the hash?

Comment: or... actually merge the hash with the results of serialize(), just like in the link you shared? ...lolm that sounds easier

Answer (score 0):

My guess is in your `serializeIntoHash`

```
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({

    serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {

        console.log(' hash going in: ' + JSON.stringify(hash)); 

        hash = this.serialize(record, options); // <---- THIS LINE

        console.log('hash going out: ' + JSON.stringify(hash)); 

        return hash;
    }

});
```

This has something to do with javascript closure. `hash` parameter's value is not changed, instead javascript created a copy of `hash` and reassigned new value to it. When the function is done, the `hash` parameter remain unchanged, and the `hash` variable would be discarded, as [Ember rest.js source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/c9d8212c857ca78218ad98d11621819b38dba98f/addon/adapters/rest.js#L728) does not expect an return value.

What you can do is

```
serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    this._super(...arguments); // ES6 Syntax

    // extract variable outside
    Object.keys(hash.someInnerVariable).forEach(key => {
      hash[key] = hash.someInnerVariable[key];
    });
    delete hash.someInnerVariable1
    delete hash.someInnerVariable2
}
```

You get the idea, alter the hash variable itself, rather than reassign its value.

Let me know if you have any further questions.